How to run anova and add significant brackets to my plot
So I can get the right barplot for each Day (below). I would like to run a one way anova within each of my Days (day 1 and day 28), DoublingTime ~ Amoxicillin * Day? and then plot the comparisons with significant bars on to my plots. Not sure how to get the plots and the anova to interact. My current anova gives every combination, but I'm only interested in within Day comparisons (0-60, 0-70, 0-80).
structure(list(Amoxicillin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("0", "60", "70", "80"), class = "factor"), 
    Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", 
    "28"), class = "factor"), DoublingTime = c(42.27, 39.38, 
    34.83, 53.32, 42.01, 43.32, 119.51, 111.8, 121.6, 96.27, 
    101.93, 99.02, 67.96, 71.46, 106.64, 133.3, 223.6, 128.36, 
    182.41, 101.93, 187.34, 99.02, 64.78, 50.59)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))


library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggpubr)
library(onewaytests)
library(rstatix)


DTData <- read.csv("C:/Users/Coral HD/R/Amox/DoublingTime/CalcDoubTime.csv")

DTDataFixed <- DTData %>% 
  mutate(Day = as.factor(Day),
         Amoxicillin = as.factor(Amoxicillin))

data_summary <- DTDataFixed %>%
  group_by(Day, Amoxicillin) %>%
  mutate(Day = as.factor(Day),
         Amoxicillin = as.factor(Amoxicillin)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_doubling_time = mean(DoublingTime),
            se = sd(DoublingTime) / sqrt(n()))

ggplot(data_summary, aes(x = Amoxicillin, y = mean_doubling_time, fill = Amoxicillin)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_doubling_time - se, ymax = mean_doubling_time + se),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Day) +
  labs(title = "Doubling Time by Day and Treatment", x = "Amoxicillin", y = "Mean Doubling Time") +
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys") 


model <- aov(DoublingTime ~ Amoxicillin * Day, data = DTDataFixed) 
#This gives every combination, but I'm only interested in within Day comparisons
summary(model)

TukeyHSD(model)



You can supply a data frame containing the comparisons you want in the geom_signif call specifying manual=TRUE.
HSD <- TukeyHSD(model)
Tukey <- data.frame(start=rep(1,6),
                   end=c(2,3,4,2,3,4),
                   Day=c(rep(1,3), rep(28,3)),
                   pVal=sprintf("%0.3f", HSD$`Amoxicillin:Day`[c(1:3, 23:25), 4]),
                   y_pos=rep(c(200,215,230),2),
                   group=1:6)

ggplot(data_summary) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Amoxicillin, y=mean_doubling_time, fill=Amoxicillin),
           stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Amoxicillin, ymin=mean_doubling_time - se, 
                    ymax=mean_doubling_time + se),
                width=0.2, position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Day) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,235)) +
  labs(title="Doubling Time by Day and Treatment", 
       x="Amoxicillin", y="Mean Doubling Time") +
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys") +
  geom_signif(data=Tukey, manual=TRUE, 
              aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, y_position=y_pos, 
                  annotations=pVal, group=group),
              textsize = 3, tip_length=0.01)



Results of Tukey`s multiple comparisons:
$`Amoxicillin:Day`
                  diff          lwr        upr     p adj
60:1-0:1      7.390000  -72.1814672  86.961467 0.9999732
70:1-0:1     78.810000   -0.7614672 158.381467 0.0531938
80:1-0:1     60.246667  -19.3248005 139.818134 0.2175507
...
60:28-0:28   79.733333    0.1618662 159.304801 0.0493448
70:28-0:28   75.206667   -4.3648005 154.778134 0.0710727
80:28-0:28  -10.556667  -90.1281338  69.014801 0.9997086


If you want the p-values from the stratified analysis, and not the one with the interaction, then you'll have to run an ANOVA for each Day, separately.
model1 <- aov(DoublingTime ~ Amoxicillin, 
              data = DTDataFixed, subset=Day==1) 
HSD1 <- TukeyHSD(model1)
HSD1


$Amoxicillin
           diff        lwr       upr     p adj
60-0    7.39000  -4.803712 19.583712 0.2849068
70-0   78.81000  66.616288 91.003712 0.0000001
80-0   60.24667  48.052955 72.440379 0.0000012


model2 <- aov(DoublingTime ~ Amoxicillin, 
              data = DTDataFixed, subset=Day==28) 
HSD2 <- TukeyHSD(model2)
HSD2


$Amoxicillin
            diff        lwr       upr     p adj
60-0   79.733333  -23.63671 183.10338 0.1401206
70-0   75.206667  -28.16338 178.57671 0.1700160
80-0  -10.556667 -113.92671  92.81338 0.9870265


format_p <- function(p) {
  p.value <- ifelse(p<0.001, "<0.001",
                    sprintf("%0.3f", p))
  }

Tukey.Day <- data.frame(start=rep(1,6),
                    end=c(2,3,4,2,3,4),
                    Day=factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(28,3))),
                    pVal= c(format_p(HSD1$`Amoxicillin`[1:3, 4]), 
                            format_p(HSD2$`Amoxicillin`[1:3, 4])),
                    y_pos=rep(c(200,215,230),2),
                    group=1:6)

ggplot(data_summary) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Amoxicillin, y = mean_doubling_time, fill = Amoxicillin),
           stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Amoxicillin, ymin = mean_doubling_time - se, ymax = mean_doubling_time + se),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Day) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,235)) +
  labs(title = "Doubling Time by Day and Treatment", x = "Amoxicillin", y = "Mean Doubling Time") +
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys") +
  geom_signif(data = Tukey.Day,
              aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, y_position=y_pos, 
                  annotations=pVal, group=group),
              textsize = 3, tip_length=0.01, manual = TRUE)




Hey thanks for helping. However, for the p-values, they are not correct. When I do this separately by Day, for instance Day 1,  I get significant p-values, and by looking on the plots some of the comparisons are obviously significant
diff        lwr       upr     p adj
60-0    7.39000  -4.803712 19.583712 0.2849068
70-0   78.81000  66.616288 91.003712 0.0000001
80-0   60.24667  48.052955 72.440379 0.0000012
70-60  71.42000  59.226288 83.613712 0.0000003
80-60  52.85667  40.662955 65.050379 0.0000034
80-70 -18.56333 -30.757045 -6.369621 0.0053900

I used the p-values from Tukey's test on the model with interactions, which is what I thought you wanted. If you want the p-values from the stratified analysis instead, see my edit.

Thank you Edward for your patience and great help.
